# Using std::count to Count number of certain char in a vector of Strings (C++)

Tags: c++, string, vector

I've looked thoroughly (I think) at all  the similar questions about this topic and I can't find a solution that works for me.

I need to count the number of specific letters (ch) inside a vector of strings, bookFile (each string contains multiple words and spaces) and test if the number of ch occurances is greater than 1.

Here's what I have right now (characters are stored in a vector, messageFile):

```
char ch = messageFile[i];
if(count(bookFile.begin(), bookFile.end(), ch) > 1){
      // do something if there are more than 1 
}
```

However i am getting this error at compile time:

```
Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) bcencode    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 3310
```

I am still new to c++ so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

**UPDATE**

I ended up with this to count the number of letters in the Vector. Thanks @Kolyan1

```
int countLetters(vector<string> &b, char ch) {
    int counter = 0;

    for (auto it = b.begin(); it != b.end(); ++it) {
        string temp_string = *it; //not strictly necessary
        counter += count(temp_string.begin(), temp_string.end(), ch);
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I vector of `string` you're searching `char`, shouldn't you be searching `string` ?

Comment: I need to find a single letter (ch) within the string.

Comment: **The** string ? Which one ? You have a whole `std::vector` of `string`s

Comment: comparison between string and ch is not possible

Comment: Post more code, its totally unclear given your current post. Do you have `vector<char>` ?

Comment: @P0W vector<string>  he will need double loop one to iterator string vector and other to iterator char in string

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Yeah I get that, but I'd not blindly assume that, only to later realize OP meant something completely different, which happens very often

Comment: With have you have posted so far, we can't help you. Post more about `bookFile`, if it is a `std::vector`, you will have to iterate it first, then `std::count` over each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is the bookFile is not a string. So, you could use some external library as: @Jarod42 posted.

(i.e. the following would work:

```
if( count(messageFile.begin(), messageFile.end(), ch) > 0){
    cout << "YOU MADE IT" << endl;
}
```

For your case to work, you need to iterate through bookfile and add-up the counts for each string as follows:

```
//assuming ch is char
//and assuming bookFile is std::vector<std::string>
int counter = 0;
for(auto it = bookFile.begin();it!=bookFile.end();++it){
    string temp_string = *it; //not strictly necessary
    counter += count(temp_string.begin(),temp_string.end(),ch);
}
if(counter>1){
 //DO Whatever
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: for pre C++11 (i.e. if auto is not supported) use: 
for(vector<string>::iterator it = bookFile.begin();  ...

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would simply be

```
std::vector<std::string> words /* = ... */;
const auto count = ranges::count(words | ranges::view::join, ch);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6a05bf95c4756a9)